# How do I fix ActionController::MissingExactTemplate: EventsController#index is missing a template for request formats: text/html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I am fixing some tests and the first line of the following test gives me this error
ActionController::MissingExactTemplate: EventsController#index is missing a template for request formats: text/html.

```
test "#index should respond to the correct format" do
    get :index, params: {id: @event.id, format: :html} #<-- this line causes problems
    assert_response :success 

    get :index, params: {id: @event.id, format: :json}
    assert_response :success 
end
```

I believe the error refers to the following method in the controllers.

```
    def index
       @events = Event.upcoming.recent
       respond_to do |format|
         format.html # index.html.erb
         format.json { render json: @events }
       end
    end
```

I am starting to consider that the line is useless but I am still unsure.

Comment: As the error states later on, you need to create a file called index.html.erb in your app/views/events folder

Answer (score 1):

If you make a json request, then `format.json { render json: @events }` will render the response.

If you make a `HTML` request, then `format.html` will look for a html file in `app/views/event/index.html.erb`

So, you need to create a file in the above location.